# Meteor FS Collection - How to loop through and retrieve CSVs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, for-loop, meteor

I have an FS collection of CSVs in Meteor declared as follows:

```
Uploads = new FS.Collection("yourFileCollection", { stores: [new
FS.Store.FileSystem("yourFileCollection", {path: "~/meteor_uploads"})]
});
```

I need to loop through each of the CSVs stored in the FS Collection to retrieve each of their paths (the paths should be unique based on the individual CSVs as they were uploaded by a user). Is this possible? Or, do I need to fix my code? And how to I loop through each of these CSVs in the Collection to retrieve them in order to perform a function on each of the CSVs?

Note: this loop will be in the following event function, which will be called when a submit button is clicked:

```
'click #parseUploads': function (event) {
}
```

Comment: Does `Uploads.find().forEach(function(csv) { ... })` not work?

Comment: How would I use it? And How would I identify (or retrieve) each of the CSVs?

Answer (score 0):

```
Uploads.find().forEach(function(f){
  console.log(f.url()); // so you can see what you're working with
  // your code
});
```